# Dependency Injection in nTier + Runtime resolution

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dependency-injection

I have been reading on Dependency Injection ([Mark Seemann: Dependency Injection in .NET](http://www.manning.com/seemann/) and various articles) to aid in my team's development of a new 3-Tier application based on EntityFramework, WCF and WPF.

I assume that we need a Composition Root on each of our tiers since they communicate through services (**DAL** <-> WCF <-> **BL** <-> WCF <-> **PL / UI**).

One of our requirements is that we need to load up and configure EF dynamically so that we can  change/expand our model after application deployment.

Without going into details on our BL --> PL/UI implementation, lets focus on our DAL that is exposed via an EntityService behind an custom serviceHost. Our project with a simple example is layed out as follows:

### Project.DataModel

- *single assembly*
- *hard references: none*
- *runtime resolution: none*
- a common library that provides abstract classes an interfaces for Data Modeling. ie EntityData abstract class

### Project.DataModel.[?]Data

- *many assemblies: ie CityData, CustomerData, etc*
- *hard references: Project.DataModel*
- *runtime resolution: none*
- a component that defines a single or multiple entities that are based on EntityData

### Project.DataModel.[?]DataConfiguration

- *many assemblies: ie CityDataConfiguration, CustomerDataConfiguration, etc*
- *hard references: Project.DataModel.[?]Data, EntityFramework*
- *runtime resolution: none*
- a component that defines EntityTypeConfiguration for the Entity(ies) defined in the previous assembly.

### Project.DataAccess

- *single assembly*
- *hard references: Project.DataModel, EntityFramework*
- *runtime resolution: Project.DataModel.[?]Data, Project.DataModel.[?]DataConfiguration*
- the data access library that provides the DbContext via an EntityManager(abstraction). At runtime this assembly looks at configuration or a directory, loads up the EntityTypes and their equivalent EntityTypeConfigurations and creates the model dynamically.

### Project.ServiceModel.EntityDataService

- *single assembly*
- *hard references: Project.DataModel, Project.DataAccess*
- *runtime resolution: none*
- A generic service that provides CRUD operations on EntityData Objects via the EntityManager class.

### Project.ServiceModel.EntityDataServiceContract

- *single assembly*
- *hard references references: Project.DataModel*
- *runtime resolution: Project.DataModel.[?]Data*
- Exposes the service contract and needs to define the ServiceKnownTypes so we need runtime resolution of EntityTypes.

### Project.ServiceHost

- *single assembly*
- *hard references: None*
- *runtime resolution: Project.ServiceModel.[?]Service, Project.ServiceModel.[?]ServiceContract*
- A custom ServiceHost that will resolve and load at runtime (either through configuration or directory scanning) various services such as EntityDataService.

This feels a lot like a plugin Project where we don't know much at compile time and there aren't many hard references between the assemblies.

How would you implement DI in this scenario. I really can't put my finger down on how and where to use DI or a DI Container, Composition Root and the lot.

Your input is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

People have a way of making dependency injection overly-complicated. If FirstClass needs a ISecondClass to work, then just make sure it can't be constructed without one. The composition root is essentially the class whose dependencies you can follow down to everything else. Make sure your interfaces all have registered instances (singleton lifetimes usually get the job done nicely), instantiate the composition root and most stuff should "just work". If it doesn't, something is more involved than it needs to be.

The WizBang application might look like this:

```
interface IThingDoerA
{
}

class ThingDoerA : IThingDoerA
{
}

interface IThingDoerB
{
}

class ThingDoerB : IThingDoerB
{
    private readonly IThingDoerA _tda;
    public ThingDoerB(IThingDoerA tda)
    {
        _tda = tda;
    }
}

interface IThingDoerC
{
}

class ThingDoerC : IThingDoerC
{
    private readonly IThingDoerA _tda;
    private readonly IThingDoerB _tdb;
    public ThingDoerC(IThingDoerA tda, IThingDoerB tdb)
    {
        _tda = tda;
        _tdb = tdb;
    }
}

// I am the composition root.
interface IWizBang
{
    public void StartApp();
}

class WizBang : IWizBang
{
    private readonly IThingDoerA _tda;
    private readonly IThingDoerC _tdc;
    public WizBang(IThingDoerA tda, IThingDoerC tdc)
    {
        _tda = tda;
        _tdc = tdc;
    }

    public void StartApp()
    {
        //TODO
        // _tda.Blah()
        // _tdc.Blah()
    }
}
```

As far as WPF is concerned, it looks like you'd be able to do a few lightweight method calls in the System.Windows.Application child class to get your app running.